# Django: manytomany relations not loaded even it exists

Tags: python, django, orm, django-oscar

We run a Django server for an ecommerce web, where thousands of queries are made, and lastly we're getting many errors like: "FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'stockrecords' into field. Choices are: ..."
I know that this error is thrown whenever we're trying to join a table through a field that doesn't exist in the model, but it really does exist.

**The query most of the time works, but It's only in certain cases that it doesn't.**

The definition of the model StockRecord is:

```
class StockRecord(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        'catalogue.Product',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="stockrecords",
        verbose_name=_("Product"))
    num_in_stock = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        _("Number in stock"), blank=True, null=True)
```

And the definition of the product does not include any reference to the stockrecords.

And the errors is produced when calling:

```
class ProductQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):

    def with_stock(self):
        return self.filter(stockrecords__num_in_stock__gt=0)
```

Like:

```
p = Product.objects.get(id=1)
# Here the exception raises
products_filtered = p.with_stock().all()
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Please share your modsel (both the `Product` and the `StockRecord`), together with the method where you use `self`. If `self` is a `Product`, you can not filter with this.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I've added the definition of the stockrecord. The product does not include any reference to the stockrecord directly, but works through the related_name.

Comment: But `self` is not a `Product`, but a `ProductQuerySet`. Exactly what are the `choices`?

Comment: Have you added `'oscar.apps.partner.apps.PartnerConfig'` (or your forked app) to installed apps? I ask because this looks like Oscar. (The `StockRecord` model is part of the `partner` app)

Comment: I've updated the question. But I think a QuerySet has the "self" as the model which is called.

Comment: Yes @AbdulAzizBarkat, it is Oscar. And the partner is installed. The problem here is that it occurs only **sometimes**.If I call it with the shell it works, but only in certain cases it does not.

Comment: Please share the full stack trace for the error - it's close to impossible to suggest what could be going on without seeing that.